# Get image from PHP displaying using an img src

Tags: php, html

The code I have should output a jpg from a list of files in a directory however it is not. I have trawled this site and tried different methods but not helped. I am a relative beginner at php so looking for any help at all.

I have tried using img src in the php code but I am trying to get the image to display within a Wordpress post so I cannot echo the img src within the script. I have tried file_get_contents and read file as well but it may be my lack of knowledge holding me back.

```
<?php
$imagepath = htmlspecialchars($_GET["image"]);
$imagenum = htmlspecialchars($_GET["num"]);

define('LOCALHOST', 'localhost' === $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );

If(LOCALHOST){
    define('PATH_IMAGES', 'this_path');
}else{
    define('PATH_IMAGES', '../../../Images/');
}

$arrnum = $GLOBALS[imagenum] - 1;
$dirname = PATH_IMAGES . $GLOBALS[imagepath]."/";
$images = scandir($dirname);
rsort($images);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");
foreach($images as $curimg){
    if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        file_get_contents('$dirname$images[$arrnum]');

        }
    }                 
?>
```

Comment: Assuming you're sending the correct image-type(are you sure they are all jpeg images) with the header, you can use `file_get_contents()` to render an image, but you need to echo the image...

Comment: when I use the following line: echo file_get_contents($dirname.$images[$arrnum]); I get the same issue as with readfile - it puts the blue square on the page and if I load up the php directly I get a lot of garbled letters etc

Comment: Then it sounds like they are not jpg files, have you tried var dump $images just to see what files it is pulling in?

Comment: The var dump of $images is string(45) "192.168.1.108_01_20181226154000368_TIMING.jpg" string(45) "192.168.1.108_01_20181226154000368_TIMING.jpg" string(45) "192.168.1.108_01_20181226154000368_TIMING.jpg" string(45)

Comment: just noticed, you seem to have forgotten a concatenation `.` between `$dirname` and `$images[$arrnum]` - use: `file_get_contents($dirname . $images[$arrnum]);`

Comment: Thank you however that has not changed it... where I was getting garble before I am not getting anything now

Comment: you also removed the single quotes around the variables `$dirname . $images[$arrnum]`? Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: I have just turned on error reporting, it has thrown the following up: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent & file_get_contents($dirname . $images[$arrnum]): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: I changed the file_get_contents back to: echo file_get_contents($dirname.$images[$arrnum]); and the only error that comes up now is Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/29/.../wp-content/themes/bridge-child/getlatestimage.php:1) in /homepages/29/...wp-content/themes/bridge-child/getlatestimage.php on line 25

Comment: yes, that's because you are sending the header on every cycle of the foreach loop, while you're also echoing in that loop. Take it out of the loop, place it above that code block. header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Comment: I have done that and it still won't load the image

Comment: no more error message(s)?

Comment: no not now, it just shows the blue box with the ? in it on both the post page and loading it directly

Comment: link if it helps http://portal.paptimelapse.com/wp-content/themes/bridge-child/getlatestimage.php?image=pap&num=1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried readfile(...); should read and output the file. In your example you are not outputting the image data

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: I have replaced file_get_contents with readfile - It still just shows the blue square which putting img src on the WP Post. When I load up the php directly using the correct variables it just shows a full screen of letters numbers and question marks in diamonds

Comment: If you're getting a screen full of letters and numbers then it sounds like a problem with the content-type . You could try Content-Type (capital T) I seem to remember something about that...

Comment: I have changed the t to a T and it has made no difference